# Как правильно перебрать массив и записать данные?

Tags: php, laravel, orm

Ребят доброго утра Всем. Такой вопрос
Принимаю склады и товары через input stringом пример(склад 1,склад 2,склад 3),
Делаю explode, перебираю через foreach, затем к этим складам добавляю продукты. Такой вопрос если склад уже существует то как мне продукты добавить уже на существующий склад, а не добавлять дубликат склада и вешать на него товары?
Сразу прошу прощение за табуляцию кода, писал его прям тут в редакторе. =) Спасибо за помощь

```
$sklads = 'склад 1, склад 2';
$skladsArr = explode(',', $sklads );

$products = 'product 1, product 2';
$productsArr = explode(',', $products );

foreach($sklads as $sklad){
$Sklad = new Sklad()
$Sklad ->name = $sklad;
$Sklad ->save()}
foreach($products as $product){
$Product= new Product();

$Product->sklad_id = $Sklad->id;
$Product->name = $product;
$Product->save()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

При условии, что массивы складов и товаров у Вас не будут огромными, я бы предложил такое решение.

```php
$sklads = 'склад 1, склад 2';
$skladsArr = explode(',', $sklads );

$products = 'product 1, product 2';
$productsArr = explode(',', $products );

//Заводим еще один массив
$skladsAndProductsArr = [];

foreach( $skladsArr as $sklad ) {
 foreach( $productsArr as $product ) {
      //В котором ключом будет название склада, а значением массив с товарами этого склада ["склад 1"] => ["product1", "product2"]
      $skladsAndProductsArr[trim($sklad)][] = trim($product);
  }   
}

//Проходим этот массив
foreach( $outArray as $sklad => $products ) {
    //На каждый его элемент-ключ заводим ОДИН раз объект Sklad
    $Sklad = new Sklad()
    $Sklad ->name = $sklad;
    $Sklad ->save();
    //Проходим массив товаров
    foreach( $products as $product ) {
        //Сохраняем каждый товар в склад созданный в родительском цикле
        $Product= new Product();
        $Product->sklad_id = $Sklad->id;
        $Product->name = $product;
        $Product->save()
    }
}
```

Comment: Это хорошее решение, но хотелось бы узнать может валидация какая нибудь нужна на проверку имени склада. Ведь если в таблицы sklads уже имеется название Склад 1, чтоб по новой не создавалась данная запись с таким же названием, а все товары которые в sklad_id ссылаются на с Склад 1 ссылались на id уже существующего склада с именем Склад 1

Comment: В таком случае реализуйте в модели `Skald` метод `findOne($params=array())` куда передавайте значения `поле => значение`, например `findOne(['name' => $sklad])` и возвращайте `sql`-запросом данные о записи если они есть. Далее проверяйте, если вернулся `null` значит с таким именем записи нет и Вы ее должны создать, если не `null` - у Вас есть `id`.